# Issues webview Android application

Tags: javascript, android, google-app-engine, android-webview, quasar

I make a web application using quasar and java spring boot backend. I convet my web application to an Android application using webview. But when i published in play store, its gives security issue for my backend server url. But i do not collect any data or install anything in Android apps or user device but Google gives an exception in my Android App. How can i fix this issue in Android web-view apps.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is sent by [Google Safe Browsing service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Safe_Browsing), which is embedded in the Google Chrome Browser and several other browsers, this service looks for vulnerabilities principally in the markup; for example open tags that could lead to a code injection or other possible threats. The Safe browsing service is independent of the GCP Serverless services, this means that GCP is not marking the site as dangerous.

To prevent this message from appearing, or remove it we can do the following:

- Look out for potential vulnerabilities in the app, once the changes have been made, you can use this [page](https://%20https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search) to see the Safe Browsing Status.
- If you think that there was a mistake, you can request a review to remove the Phishing Warning in this [site](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/).
- It is highly recommended to take a look a this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/request_review) to understand what could be the reason behind the message

Answer (score 0):

My issue is now fixed. It ended up being a hosting server issue. Google had me on a black list, but now its fixed.